# How to remotely change slides out of order when displayed on an iPad?

Tags: remote-control, ipad, slideshow

For a psychology experiment a friend of mine is looking for a possibility to show phrases on an iPad screen which can be controlled from outside. (Laptop, second iPad)

There will be around 100 Phrases (probably on slides). And the it should be possible to make the iPad jump to any slide but without interacting with it.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Your friend could set up a Keynote presentation on the iPad.

The Keynote presentation can then be remote controlled from the second iPad with [Keynote Remote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote-remote/id300719251?mt=8):

> Keynote Remote lets you control a Keynote presentation on your Mac, iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch from another iPhone or iPod touch in the room.
>
> While you present, view your current slide and presenter notes in portrait, or the current slide and next slide in landscape. Swipe forward to advance and swipe back to return to the previous slide.

As for randomizing, this won't be easily possible with Keynote—you can only [script it with AppleScript on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451371/how-to-randomize-keynote-slides), but there are apps like [Screens](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-control-your-computer/id400012962?mt=8) and others that would turn the iPad into a remote screen for a computer so you could do your randomizing and controlling remotely.

A custom web app or setting up a web server that cycled among random images each time you tapped the screen would be also inexpensive to code, but it's not really using presentation software and you'd need to have a remote to toggle the change if touching the screen was really not an option.

Comment: Sounds good, but is it possible from the Keynote to jump to any Slide by tapping a slide number?

Comment: From [the manual](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3325) it doesn't appear so. If you need to have randomized slides, all you could probably do is create randomized slideshows beforehand, using AppleScript to mix up the slides as linked to in the Stack Overflow post. An alternative would be to have the iPad connect via remote desktop to another PC or Mac which actually runs the slides, or shows the text as images in a randomized fashion.

Comment: Sorry, with Random access I didn't think of randomized slides. But to jump to any slide of choice. At the end it should be possible to show slides on the iPad depending of the answer of the user taking the test.

Comment: I see. It doesn't seem to be possible with the Keynote Remote. I'd suggest going the other way and connecting to a computer via VNC or other remote desktop services, then doing the presentation there.